# Python replace text (regex?)

Tags: python, regex, replace, urllib2

I have a Problem with the replace function. I can print the link but I can't replace the link. Which code I have forgotten?

```
import urllib2
import re

htmlfile = urllib2.urlopen('http://sample.html')
htmltext = htmlfile.read()
regex = "'nav_a'>(.+?)</a></li>"
pattern = re.compile(regex)
link = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)

downloadlink = link.replace("*text to replace*", "*replace with*")

print (downloadlink)
```

Comment: I'll bet your English is better than my German (I only recall tiny bits from my class long ago). Do you mean that `downloadlink` is just the original text with no replacements? You'll need to share what your regex expressions are.

Comment: @ mbratch http://codeviewer.org/view/code:34c4

(This is an example. The output is not a link but the principle is resembles)

Comment: Please edit the question instead.

Comment: @Emil Lundberg what do you mean?

Comment: What I did in my edit suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of `re.findall()`, it will return a *list* of all non-overlapping matches in the string. Hence you cannot do `link.replace()` since `link` is a list, not string.

You have to loop over each element in `link` and do the replace. For example,

```
links = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
downloadlinks = []

for link in links:
    downloadlinks.append(link.replace("*text to replace*", "*replace with*"))

print(downloadlinks)
```

Edit (convert list to str):

```
links = re.findall(pattern,htmltext)
downloadlinks = ''

for i, link in enumerate(links):
    if i == 0:
        downloadlinks += link
    else:
        downloadlinks += ' - ' + link

print(downloadlinks)
```

Comment: But I can not replace that (words are working): http://codeviewer.org/view/code:34c6

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are asking, but `downloadlinks` is another list - so you can see each link by `downloadlinks[0]`, `downloadlinks[1]`, etc.

Comment: For example I would like to copy this to the clipboard (or print): Today's Deals - Gift Cards - Sell - Help. But now python copy this to the clipboard: ["Today's Deals", 'Gift Cards', 'Sell', 'Help']. This marks must be removed: [ " , ' ].

Comment: As I said, `[,]` are there because downloadlinks is a list - they are delimiters which automatically get printed out. Read Python documentation about list and strings.

Comment: I edited the answer with converting list to a string part. But please see the documentation as well - you need to know it for the future usage.

Comment: A lot of many thanks. It functions again :D. You have helped me very much